# Microsoft Bot Framework with NodeJs sdk version 4.0 not allow multiple users sessions

Tags: node.js, botframework

My bot developed with NodeJS and bot framework 4.0 using the based code of the samples keeps variables values from session to session.
The first user populate name, email and phone number and in the next session with same or different browser the values stick, it seems like nodejs creates a singleton or maybe IIS hosting nodejs cached the values, this creates problems with concurrent users.

I am using an angular app based on an angular web chat sample using direct line to pass a random id to the bot, I though the bot framework will resolve the unique session for each user but its not happening.

Help is need it I am stuck for days!
Thanks in advance.
Jose

Comment: Hello, which code sample are you following for the node bot? If you could post what you have tried so far, it would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, the bot.js module below the variables

Comment: Hi, the bot.js module these variables userid, name etc retain the value of first user async onTurn(turnContext) {
        if(turnContext.activity.type === 'event'){ 
             await turnContext.sendActivity(`inside activity event`);
           userId =turnContext.activity.from.id;
           localTime=turnContext.activity.localTimestamp;
           await turnContext.sendActivity(`inside event activity`);
           await turnContext.sendActivity(name + ' ' + email + ' ' + phone + '' + userId);

Comment: const { LuisRecognizer } = require('botbuilder-ai');
const { ActivityTypes } = require('botbuilder');
const { QnA } = require('./qna');
const { VehicleLookUp }=require('./vehicleLookUp');
const { ProvideInfo } = require('./provideinfo')
const { BlobStorage } = require("botbuilder-azure");
const shared = require('./shared');
const DISPATCH_CONFIG = 'UVS-dispatch';
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var storage;
var botUserState;
var userId;
var isRecurrentUser;  
var recurrentUserName; 
let name;    
let email;    
let phone;

Comment: I am using a direct line angular app and passed a unique user id with a post activity of type "event" with a couple of variables as local time and local timezone

Comment: direct line code:   public ngOnInit(): void {
const directLine = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({secret: "",webSocket: false});
const userId = `${Date.now() + Math.random().toString(36)}`;
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({directLine: directLine,userID: userId},this.botWindowElement.nativeElement);directLine.postActivity({from: { id:  genUniqueId()},localTimestamp:new Date(),localTimestamp1:new Date().toTimeString().slice(9),text: "requestWelcomeDialog",type: "event",value: "token"})
.subscribe( id => console.log(`Posted activity, assigned ID ${id}`),error=>console.log(`${error}`));

Comment: how can I send you the code? this comment boxes are very small

Comment: Hello, you can edit your question and post your code by enclosing them in three or more back ticks. Refer to [this](https://i.imgur.com/5ntLb0u.png)

Comment: I found my issue was with the direct line code I was passing different unique ids, but I need help on how to get the accessor for properties in userState object that is passed to another JavaScript file provideinfo.js from bot.js  this is my bot.js code

Comment: I enclose the code in back ticks ``` but still not allowing exceed 1000+ characters, let me show you the minimum I save successfully the userState in a blob storage from bot.js then I passed in this line to another file switch (dispatchTopIntent) {
                case INFO_INTENT:
                case 'yes':
                    await this.infoDialog.onTurn(turnContext, this.userState );

Comment: in provideinfo.js I need to read the values of the properties  async onTurn(turnContext,userState) {
 this line only return the name this.welcomedUserProperty = userState.properties.get(WELCOMED_USER); but I need the value and how to setup a new value in that file, sorry new to nodejs it is very simple in c#  thank you very much for your help, I think the main issue at this moment is that

Comment: Dude. Hit the 'edit' button on your question (it's under the tags) and add the code to the actual question. There's no need to be putting it all in comments, and it makes it super hard for anyone to read/help. Stop putting it in comments. It's making everyone confused.

Comment: Apologize for the confusion, its my first question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved, the problem was the direct line code sent two different ids to the bot instead of a single id in both activities and not using UserState object to persist data to some storage (I used the azure blob storage) instead of Memory storage.  Thank you